# React on Rails - ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, git, heroku, react-on-rails

I'm working in rails 4.2.5, recently I have added `react_on_rails` in my app. I am getting the error(mkdir: cannot create directory) when I try to deploy the code on Heroku. App uses couple of webpacks one for Ruby and another for Node.

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 963, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (793/793), done.
Writing objects: 100% (963/963), 982.20 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 963 (delta 384), reused 160 (delta 70)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Deleting 18 files matching .slugignore patterns.
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/build_2116c2c5be27b9852c9d716798b3bcf9/.heroku’: Not a directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to acceptance.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/acceptance.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku team helped resolve this issue - answer from Heroku team:

> It looks like this project has a ".heroku" file checked into its root
>   directory, which collides with the ".heroku" directory used to install
>   runtimes like node, php, etc. You can keep this file from being pushed
>   to Heroku by adding it to your .slugignore file like this:

```
echo ".heroku" >> .slugignore

git commit -am 'ignore .heroku file'
```